# SQL scripts challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wondering if anyone can help me with below logic?
One UEN may have Multiple values for Role column, but I only need those 'Channel Partner', for the rest I only need null value, and pick anyone name & email to avoid those UEN being excluded with unique row of records in this table.
In the end, one UEN should have unique row of data, Role field should be 'Channel Partner' or Null.

How to compile this SQL then?

Here is the sample data in a Table

```
|UEN            | Role              | name      |email       |
|:-------------:|:-----------------:|:---------:|:-----------|
|200816596R     |ACCOUNT MANAGER    |Person 1   |1@google.com|
|200816596R     |CHANNEL PARTNER    |Person 2   |2@google.com|
|200816596R     |DIRECTOR           |Person 3   |3@google.com|
|200816596R     |LEAD DIR           |Person 4   |4@google.com|
|200816596R     |TEAM HEAD          |Person 5   |5@google.com|
|200816596R     |ICT SALES MANAGER  |Person 6   |6@google.com|
|200918253E     |ACCOUNT MANAGER    |Person 7   |7@google.com|
|200918253E     |CHANNEL PARTNER    |Person 8   |8@google.com|
|200918253E     |DIRECTOR           |Person 9   |9@google.com|
|200918253E     |LEAD DIR           |Person 10  |10@google.com|
|200918253E     |TEAM HEAD          |Person 11  |11@google.com|
|200918253E     |ICT SALES MANAGER  |Person 12  |12@google.com|
|201420866M     |ACCOUNT MANAGER    |Person 13  |13@google.com|
|201420866M     |DIRECTOR           |Person 14  |14@google.com|
|201420866M     |LEAD DIR           |Person 15  |15@google.com|
|C00000019951   |ACCOUNT MANAGER    |Person 18  |18@google.com|
|C00000019951   |CHANNEL PARTNER    |Person 19  |19@google.com|
|C00000019951   |LEAD DIR           |Person 20  |20@google.com|
|C00000019951   |TEAM HEAD          |Person 21  |21@google.com|
```

Comment: ... and don't post pictures in the first place. Give us some meaningful data as text (code section) and provide some code (which sql system are you using?).

Comment: Here attached some sample data, hope you can understand. Thank you!

Comment: I‘m using SQL server. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (and expected results here would help) you want 1 row per UEN, the *Channel Partner* row if it exists and NULL if not, and the *Name* and *Email* values can be any.

You can do this using `row_number` to assign a priority based on the value of `role`
and then select one row for each unique `UEN`

```
select UEN,
    case when [Role] ='CHANNEL PARTNER' then [Role] else null end Role, 
    [Name], 
    Email
from (
    select *, 
        Row_Number() over(partition by UEN order by case [Role] when 'CHANNEL PARTNER' then 0 else 1 end) rn
    from t
)t
where rn=1
```

Comment: Hi Stu,

Sorry for my late gratitude, above solution worked at my end.
Thank you very much!!